# Exporting Lotus Notes document to CSV & Excel Files

Tags: lotus-notes, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

Can Anyone suggest me which method (freefile or ole object creation) is Efficient to export lotus notes documents to CSV and Excel files?

Answer (score 3):

i used formula as well to export as csv & excel.

@Command([FileExport]; "Comma Separated Value"; "c:\text.csv")

Answer (score 1):

Efficient? Use a NotesDXLExporter to export to DXL/XML. See [link](http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21206902). Easy? Select the document in a view and use File/Export, Save as type: Comma Separated Value. You can prepare your own view with the data you need exported.

Answer (score 0):

i got the below simple code for exporting CSV files.

[[Link]](http://www.falsepositives.com/files/ViewCSVPrint.txt)

```
fileNum% = Freefile()
Open filename For Output As fileNum%

' use the view column titles as the CSV headers
Forall c In view.Columns
    If cns = "" Then    
        cns = c.title
    Else
        cns = cns + +","  + c.title         
    End If
End Forall      
Print #fileNum%, cns


 ' now get and print the values for each row and column
Set vc = view.AllEntries
Set entry = vc.GetFirstEntry()
While Not entry Is Nothing 
    rowstring = ""
    Forall colval In entry.ColumnValues
        If rowstring = "" Then
            rowstring = colval
        Else
            rowstring = rowstring + +","  + colval
        End If          
    End Forall
    Print #fileNum%, rowstring
    Set entry = vc.GetNextEntry(entry)
Wend
Close fileNum%
```

Comment: Now i'm trying to import data from CSV file